# Unable to center/properly scale button and label in view using constraints?

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints

Im having a frustrating problem as I've worked with constraints in the past and have simply used the "Add missing constraints" to do the job, however I am having a LOT of difficulty achieving something very simple -

I have a larger button and a label positioned on my xib file. I need both these centered horizontally and scale with the device, and more or less maintain the distance between each other. Basically just need them to look reasonably good and for the button (which has an image within it) to scale but maintain aspect ratio.

Add missing constraints has not worked in the least as this results in neither the button nor label scaling (both stay small) and the space between them being too big on larger screens. I've tried every other constraint configuration but the button just ends up being squished or going off the screen. Here is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

The troublemaker is the button. Is there a way to do this programmatically? I am desperate here. How can I configure the constraints?

How do you set a distance between 2 objects?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Center the button horizontally and vertically with the view. Center the label to the view and give vertical spacing from button to the label. Also give width constraint to label if necessary. This will give you the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

**For UIButton:**

1.Centre Horizontally & centre vertically

2.Give Aspect ration (or) use leading,trailing,top,button for scale it to different device.

**For UILabel**

1.Centre it horizontally.

2.Set vertical to the UIButton.

2.Set Aspect ratio.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I am trying to follow your directions but am having some difficulty - with step 2 for the label, which button/how do you set the bottom distance between a label and a button? I posted a picture of the buttons I have

Comment: If you can't set bottom just set vertical space

Comment: How do I do that? It is not working the button is being scaled to run off the screen

Comment: I have followed all of your instructions verbatim for the button and yet on smaller devices its not even visible

Comment: use the middle of those three buttons. then do this [link](http://postimg.org/image/g2kt8j2sr/)

Comment: I have posted a picture of what Ive done. Still not working